# How to put VueScan in applications start menu

Tags: scanner

I am trying to install vuescan as it has a user-friendly interface for using my Epson V370 flatbed scanner. If I install via flatpak, that version doesn't find my scanner.

However, Version 9.6.22 works from terminal after cutting and pasting directions for install at https://linuxg.net/how-to-install-vuescan-on-linux/. But, it doesn't put an link in my applications menu.

Also,  after restarting my laptop again today, the ./vuescan command wasn't recognised although that may possibly be related to tinkering to resolve my earlier question.

I would like to get vuescan going as it may be an acceptable solution for me in Linux - I use ABBYY FineReader with Windows and have struggled to find anything close to paralleling the FineReader experience in Linux. VueScan I can work with (probably with additional image editing software) if I can get it to run consistently.

Comment: What OS/release are you using? (inc. flavor).

Answer (score 1):

Using Ubuntu 20.04 with Cinnamon-mate desktop.

I managed to solve. Created launcher on desktop and opted to have copy in Other folder. Found out how to use Menu Editor to shift launcher into a different group.